# How to handle button click event from INCLUDE TAG in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Include Tag in my `Main.xml`, which has button inside of it.

#### Main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/preferences"
        layout="@layout/activity_panel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></include>
</LinearLayout>
```

How to handle button click event from include tag layout? Because i will re-use this INCLUDE tag in many pages.